# Table propane fire pit not igniting

Tags: gas, furniture, natural-gas, table, gas-burner

enter image description here[image: fire pit]

I have a propane fire pit table that has been working very well for several years. I was planning on staining my deck so I had to take my table apart and bring it inside. When I brought it inside a bunch of fine powder from crushed stones might have found its way into the tubing for the gas because now when I turn my propane on, no gas gets to the burner. I tried taking it apart and blowing out the lines but it did not seem to help. Is there another way to fix this issue that I'm not thinking of? Thank you.

Comment: garden hose, wash it out let it dry

Comment: Do you smell gas when you try to light it?  if so, have you tried lighting with one of those small "clicker" propane lighters,...the kind that are often used to light candles.

Comment: maybe you are out of gas

Comment: Awesome idea with the garden hose, I will try that. I don't smell or hear any gas when I turn the regulator which is leading me to believe that there is a blockage in the line somewhere. I tried lighting the ring with a lighter and it did not work. I also verified that there is plenty of propane in the tank by attaching the tank to my griddle which worked fine.